# Jenkinsfile calling a pipeline from a library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have 2 repositories with a pipeline that is just the same, except for the values of 4 variables at the beginning of the code. The repositories are for production and development environment.

I want to write the pipeline as a library and call it from the repositories passing the variables as parameters.  Is it possible?

I have tried doing the library like this:
**pipelineDeployBq2bq.groovy**

```
def call(Map variable1, Map variable2, Map variable3, Map variable4){
…

pipeline{
 ...
 }
}
```

and calling from the **Jenkinsfile** in the repository like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      label "xxxxxx"
      yamlFile 'xxxxxx'
    }
  }

  environment {
    PROJECT_TYPE = xxxxxxx
  }

  stages {

    stage('Stage 1') {
      steps {
        pipelineDeployBq2bq(prfBuckets, environmentProjects, pubSubByEnvironment, composerTags)
      }
    }
  }//End stages
}//End pipelines
```

But I got an error like this

```
Only one pipeline { ... } block can be executed in a single run.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem here is calling `pipeline` twice in the same declarative pipeline (which is by definition impossible).
A solution if your pipeline contains multiple stages (it works totally fine with just one stage too) is doing

```
def call(Map variable1, Map variable2, Map variable3, Map variable4){
 stage('Stage1'){
  steps{...
  }
 }
 stage('StageX'){
  steps{...
  }
 }
}
```

And calling it in your pipeline like that :

```
pipeline{ //all your setup stuff 
 stages {  
  pipelineDeployBq2bq(prfBuckets,environmentProjects,pubSubByEnvironment, composerTags)
  stage('Stage 2'){
   ...
  }
 }//End of stages
}//End of pipeline
```